# Expected number of Bernoulli trials before at least s successes and f failures

Tags: probability-distributions, power-series, expected-value, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial

Let a random variable $X$ be the number of independant Bernoulli trials needed to reach $s$ successes and $f$ failures when the probability of success is $p$. We therefore stop trials when we have $s$ successes and at least $f$ failures OR $f$ failures and at least $s$ successes.

I do not know if a probablity distribution modeling such $X$ is described in the probability literature, but I figured it could be written as follows
\begin{equation}
 P(X=x) =
 \begin{cases}
  \binom{s+f}{s}p^{s}(1-p)^{f} & \text{if $x=s+f$}\\
  \binom{x-1}{s-1}p^{s}(1-p)^{x-s}+\binom{x-1}{f-1}(1-p)^{f}p^{x-f} & \text{if $x>s+f$}\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
where the first part is therefore the probability to get exactly $s$ successes (and therefore $f$ failures) in $s+f$ trials. And the second part is a weighted sum of two negative binomials.

I would like to find the expected value of $X$, function of $s$ and $f$.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you knew specific values for $s,f$ and $p$, you could set up a recursion
$$E(s,f)=1+pE(s-1,f)+(1-p)E(s,f-1)\\
E(s,0)=1+pE(s-1,0)+(1-p)E(s,0)\\
E(0,f)=1+pE(0,f)+(1-p)E(0,f-1)$$
So, for example  $E(s,0)=s/p$ and $E(0,f)=f/(1-p)$, and build up from there.
For any possible path from $(s,f)$ to $(0,0)$, you might consider the last point on the grid before one of the entries is zero, because each step becomes more expensive from then on.
$$E(s,f)=\sum_{e=1}^f{s-1+f-e\choose s-1}p^{s}(1-p)^{f-e}(s+f-e+e/(1-p))+\\
\sum_{r=1}^s{s-r+f-1\choose f-1}p^{s-r}(1-p)^f(f+s-r+r/p)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you think it would make sense or would be possible to adapt the probability function to a continous distribution where s, f, and therefore x would be non-negative reals? And if yes, how would you derive its expected value

Comment: For large s and f, the most likely intersection point with an edge is where sucesses and failures have been exactly in the ratio p to 1-p.  So you can predict the most likely leftover, which you have to divide by p or 1-p respectively.  I'm not sure what the variance would be.